# Why is theme not used in my remote site when it is in my local site?

Tags: 8

I just installed Drupal 8.9.13 locally with Composer: `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project:8.9.13 mySite`.
Then I copied all files to remote site.
Then I launched Drupal installer: `http://path/to/site/core/install.php` on both local and remote sites in parallel.
The process went to its end with no problem but (there is a but) the remote site doesn't look very nice...

Local site:
[image: Local site]

Remote site:
[image: Remote site]

Any idea of what went wrong?

Comment: Probably file permissions (aggregated CSS/JS files not being written)

Comment: Is it in `/sites/default/files/css` and `/sites/default/files/js`? And what should be the permissions for sites, default, files, css/js? I tried to look for some documentation about this and couldn't find anything simple and "obvious".

Comment: Info: The problem disappears when I uncheck `Aggregate CSS files` in `/admin/config/development/performance/Bandwidth optimization`. But what can II do if I want to keep this setting?

Comment: this happens cause drupal tries to aggregate all CSS and JS files used in theme into two files for performance but when it tries to write aggregated file into `sites/default/files` it faces permission denied, then cause aggregate check is checked drupal tries to find and fetch css from tehre but it is not exist. so just follow the instruction in my answer to get drupal permissions it needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options:

1. Your production server might not handle a `.htaccess` file well that lives in `sites/default/files`.

Or

2. can't write to the `tmp` folder.

To check this out:
first visit `admin/reports/dblog` and read the errors.

Second:
***note*** clear browser history first!

1. you can comment out all lines of code in the `.htaccess` file.
2. Upload file to your production server.
3. visit `admin/config/development/performance`
4. click `clear all caches`

Comment: It seems it was about temp folder permissions...

Answer (score 0):

Drupal must have access to modify files directory (it needs write permission) `/sites/default/files` so you'd better to change owner and group of this directory.

if you have ssh access use these commands:

`cd WEBROOT/sites/default`

`sudo chown www-data:www-data files`

and then

`sudo chmod 755 files`

else you can use cpannel or directadmin or etc to change this directory owner and permissions.

Comment: I don't have SSH access for the remote site. I used FTP to change permissions: even with 777 on sites, default, files, css and js folders, it doesn't work!

Comment: 777 is not secure at all, clear the cache first (so drupal will create needed aggregate files) and then reset the permission to 755 again, keep in mind that files/css and files/js needs to have temporary 777 permissions.